# redirect from http to https but showing variables in new result

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using a redirect in .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Seems to work fine until i see the redirect shows variables.
Example page http://www.myserver.com/category/pagename
When i was using http only before redirect added worked fine.
But now shows similar to http://www.myserver.com/main.php?category=name&pagename=pagename

Any idea how to ensure it does not put in these variables ?

Comment: Add redirect rules before rewrite in your htaccess

Comment: ..and then clear your browser cache to test the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the QSD flag(Discard Query String)

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Musa : QSD will discard QueryString from all http to https URLs. I don't think this is what the OP wants.